# What is the word that means to offer to be in a relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word that means to offer to be in a relationship. For example, it could be used in the following dialogue:

> A: Let's go over to my apartment.
>   B: Are you [] me?

However, I can't think of this word. Any help?

Comment: Rather than an offer to be in a relationship, it sounds like something else :D eheheh

Comment: @Alennano DIMSOC?

Comment: @Sdsf how about: _Are you trying to get me?_

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: ?

Comment: @Aleanno, yes my dear?

Comment: @sdsf, your conversation example does not really illustrate typical scenario where a relationship is discussed.

Comment: @Unreason: Exactly what I meant... :D

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: I believe @Alenanno's original question amounted to "WTF is DIMSOC?"  At least, that is *my* question. ;)  My best guess is it stands for "Did I Miss Something of Consequence", though that sounds too stilted.  It would be more amusing and intriguing if it was in fact a typo for SIMSOC, though.

Comment: In this facebook age, I think that is 'friending'

Comment: @Ham Do you mean *Are you trying to get with me?* That would make more sense.

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: what does "DIMSOC" mean?

Comment: "DIMSOC" is an expression derived from DIMS?. DIMS? stands for "Does it make sense?" and is used for situations which are really DIMS? DIMSOC stands for DIMS Of Course!

Comment: @sdsf asking someone back to your apartment is not necessarily offering to be in a relationship with them, it's generally suggesting getting intimate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first word that springs to mind is *proposition*, as in

> Are you propositioning me?

That would generally imply sex rather than necessarily a longer relationship, but that would seem to fit your example dialogue :-)

Other possible words include: *seduce*, *woo*, *pursue*.

Comment: Nice one. Sounds a bit formal though

Comment: Never end a sentence with a proposition ;)

Comment: *Proposition* is rarely used in the active voice...

Comment: *Woo* is a really good suggestion, though, depending on what the OP is going for.

Comment: @Jimi I think the *only* time I hear "propositioning" is in this exact context. @psmears I think the equivalent is "Are you asking to have sexual relations with me?" so it's not at all about a longer relationship, but I agree that is fits the dialogue best.  It's what immediately popped into my mind when I read it.

Comment: To those non-native speakers who might be inclined to try to use these terms, 'proposition' and 'seduce' might actually be used, but sounds like a movie script (as in not really an accurate view of reality); if used, they really might be considered too presumptuous. 'Woo', on the other hand, _no one would ever dare utter_ in those circumstances, except possibly by someone with a psychosis brought on by an overdose of Wodehouse novels...sorry, novels read by characters in Wodehouse novels.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proposition?show=1&t=1309740436) and [Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proposition?region=us) definitions for "to proposition" agree.

Answer (score 39):

I usually use:
Are you hitting on me?
:-)

Comment: Congratulations!  You maxed out your daily rep on your very first answer!

Answer (score 19):

For an option which is slightly less sexual than *proposition* or *hitting on*, you might say:

> Are you **coming on to me**?

Where *to come on to someone* means to flirt and entice someone, without necessarily implying that you're asking for a sexual act, which is what *to proposition* implies.

Comment: "Flirting" might be even better (less sexual connotation that "coming on" in my opinion). But the OP's word "relationship" suggests to me something more lasting than "flirting with" or "coming on to" or "hitting on" does.

Comment: You might say to her: " Would you tell your breasts to stop staring at my eyes?"

Answer (score 6):

> Are you courting me?

This better implies seeking a relationship rather than just a sexual liaison.  Though its use is kind of out of 
fashion.

*[Courting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/court)* means "to woo; to attempt to win over with social activities and displays of tact and affection."

Comment: That's probably the most accurate word to fit what he's looking for. But nobody would ever say that out loud.

Answer (score 2):

*Diggin*. I think that you would want to know if they got your implication, and *diggin* is slang from the 60–70s.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, when a man (or in recent times a woman) asks their love interest to become their spouse, that is a "propoosal", and the verb is "to propose". However, in modern times we would define that couple as being "in a relationship" long before it gets to this point.

Less formally, an implicit or explicit invitation from one person to another to have a romantic or sexual encounter is to "proposition" them; the term is officially a noun, but got "verbed" as many nouns implying an action tend to do. Again, this is normally between people who have at least some personal relationship prior to the invitation, but this relationship could be as short as a shared drink or two at a bar.

Other such terms, as stated in other answers, include "to seduce", "to come on to", "to hit on", "to dig on", "to flirt with", "to break the ice", etc. These all have the connotation of more or less an implied invitation to participate, and some are more innocent and/or introductory than others. You can "hit on" or "flirt with" total strangers with no serious invitation implied, depending on the social setting. "Seducing" a total stranger is possible, but nearly always implies a very serious invitation to romance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the word "courting" is appropriate in your example.